# Series with convergence test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

[image]

This is comparison of D'Alembert and Cauchy tests for convergent series.

For proof of $2$-nd one take $D=\varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$(limit superior)

then there is some $n_0$ $s.t$ $n\geq n_0$ $a_{n+1}<(D+\epsilon)a_n$ for any $\epsilon.$

doing $n-n_0$ times we get.

[image]

from this we get.

[image]

How I go proving first one?

Thought that $D=\varliminf_{\,n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$(limit inferior)$

Then $a_n >D-\epsilon$
from here don't know how to continue?

Comment: Mathjax , use mathjax at 400 plus points one should know better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\displaystyle D = \varliminf_{\,n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $k \geqslant n_0$ we have $\displaystyle \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}> D-\epsilon$.

Thus, with $k = n_0$,

$$a_{n_0+1} \geqslant (D-\epsilon)a_{n_0}$$

and with  $k = n_0+1$,
$$a_{n_0+2} \geqslant (D-\epsilon)a_{n_0+1}\geqslant (D-e)^2a_{n_0}$$

It follows by induction that for all $j \geqslant 1$, we have $\displaystyle a_{n_0+j}\geqslant (D-\epsilon)^ja_{n_0}$, and taking $n = n_0+j> n_0$,

$$a_n \geqslant (D-\epsilon)^n\frac{a_{n_0}}{((d-\epsilon)^{n_0}}$$

Hence,
$$\sqrt[n]{a_n} \geqslant (D-\epsilon)\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_{n_0}}{((d-\epsilon)^{n_0}}}$$

We then have,

$$\varliminf_{\,n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\geqslant (D-\epsilon)\varliminf_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_{n_0}}{((d-\epsilon)^{n_0}}}= (D-\epsilon)\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_{n_0}}{((d-\epsilon)^{n_0}}}= D- \epsilon$$

This must hold for all $\epsilon >0$ and the first result follows.